# AVPlayer Play when coming back from other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I setup an `AVPlayer` as a layer to my view, When I present a `UIViewController` I'm pausing the video by setting the rate to 0, and in view will appear I set the rate back to one.

I also have a notification on `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` which do the same thing (pause on background, play on foreground)...

When I present a VC and then come back, I can't get the video to continue playing, however when I go to background and come back - it plays just fine..

Not sure what I'm missing..

This is how I setup the player

```
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:videoUrl];
    self.player.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;

    self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    self.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    self.playerLayer.player.muted = YES;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:self.playerLayer atIndex:0];
```

Comment: how are you dismissing the presented VC ?

Comment: It uses an unwindSegue

Comment: It looks like it behaves much better if I recreate the layer and insert it every time.

Comment: add your `viewWillAppear` code to your question as well, are you sure it is fired? but a break point to see what happens. try `viewDidAppear` to see if it is going to make any difference